# Linking Failure Using _stat to Get File Creation Time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, linker-errors, stat

I am porting an existing application from Apple to Windows. The following sample is trying to link _stat to my application.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

uint64_t MZFilePath::getFileCreationDate(void)
{
    struct _stat stat_t;
    uint64_t creationDate = 0L;
    int results = 0;

    results = _stat((const char *) m_native_path, &stat_t);

    //if (results == 0)
    //{
    //  creationDate = stat_t.st_ctime;
    //}

    return creationDate;
}
```

I have a static library that contains the following function. Linking to an example application yields the following linker errors:

```
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '___lc_codepage_func' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(initctype.obj)' is imported by 'msvcprt.lib(filesystem.obj)' in function '__std_fs_code_page'
1>MZFrame.lib(MZFilePath.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__stat64i32 referenced in function "public: unsigned __int64 __cdecl MZFilePath::getFileCreationDate(void)" (?getFileCreationDate@MZFilePath@@QEAA_KXZ)
1>D:\Sandbox\Visual Studio\MarkzFrame\x64\Debug\Converter.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "Converter.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 6 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Thanks,

Willie Peloquin

Comment: I don't have the VS 2019 so my inability to reproduce this one isn't much of a surprise. Here's a slightly better [mre]: https://godbolt.org/z/rowECn . Create a brand new project and see if that works.If it does you'll have to track down the difference between it and your real project. If it doesn't... Your tools are missing a library somewhere.

Comment: Defined in ucrtd.lib but you're linking libucrt.lib.  You can't mix /MDd compiled code with /MTd compiled code, only ever used /MD for code that gets linked into a DLL.  That warning has a similar cause.